# Most efficient way to pass data from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, memcpy

I am looking for the best way to transfer a large amount of data from C++ (struct or a value class?) into a C# class doing as little data copying as possible.   In the sample code below, I have a vector of SubClass objects that has the potential to be very large (10+ million).   So I want to avoid a data copy if possible.

Should I/can I just allocate the objects in GC first and use them directly in c++ and forget about the native c++ structures?  (Performance is my concern with this one.)

Or,  is there some trick that I leverage what is allocated in C++ without causing a data copy?

Here is a sample of something along the lines of what I want to use as a transfer between managed and unmanaged code.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
struct SubClass {
    std::string DataItem1;
    // lots more here
    std::string DataItem50;
};

struct Sample {
    int IntValue;
    std::string StringValue;
    std::vector<std::string> SmallList;
    std::vector<SubClass> HugeList;
};
```

If I can avoid getting into the weeds with pinvoke and COM classes, I would prefer it.

Comment: Is your C++ code part of a DLL?

Comment: Yes.  I am writing the DLL code, so I don't need to try to work with a third party closed DLL.

I am currently writing the DLL to work directly with the CLI objects, but this means that I have to write two routines to do the same thing.   One for the .NET side and one for the C++ side.

Having a wrapper would isolate the layers, but at the cost of performance, it may not be the right choice.

Perhaps there is a typename way of doing this where I can toggle between a .NET build and a c++ build and save myself re-coding?

Comment: You should be able to pass the C# reference of the SubClass into the c++ DLL. You need to make sure the data members line up. Here is an stackoverflow article to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939867/passing-a-structure-to-c-api-using-marshal-structuretoptr-in-c-sharp

Comment: This requires a copy because you can't marshal variable arrays.   Unfortunately, I have that situation all over the place.  To boot the sub classes (100+) are so deep and heavily overloaded (probably up 12 levels deep), that even to create something using marshalling would be a challenge.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to use std::string and std::vector without copying.

Answer (score 1):

Following the example from Unity (who uses C#), [Native plugin example](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/NativeRenderingPlugin/blob/master/UnityProject/Assets/UseRenderingPlugin.cs) uses a GC handle to transfer data from C# to C++. We can try the opposite to send data to C++ from C#.

Pin down a C# variable to allow faster copying.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
// vertices is a Vector3[], where Vector3 is a struct 
// of 3 floats using a sequential layout attribute
void test(){
GCHandle gcVertices = GCHandle.Alloc (vertices, GCHandleType.Pinned); 
}
```

Transfer the handle to C++ using marshaling. It's unavoidable that you have to copy something. Here copying a pointer should be good enough. More on marshaling according to Microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-data-with-platform-invoke).

```cs
[DllImport("your dll")]
private static extern void SendHandle(IntPtr vertexHandle, int vertexCount);
SendHandle(gcVertices, vertices.Length);
```

Inside C++, you'll receive the handle as a pointer type to a C++ type of your choosing. In this case, `vertices` are a list of structs of 3 floats. The reference code decided to use `float *`. You just need to do pointer arithmetic properly depending on the pointed type, including the case of `void *`.

```cpp
extern "C" __decl(dllexport) void SendHandle(float* vertices, int vertexCount);
```

Here the example code copies data directly from the pointer, but you can also write to the pointer's location.

```cpp
for (int i = 0 ; i < vertexCount; i++)
{
   // read from C# heap
   float x = vertices[0];
   float y = vertices[1];
   float z = vertices[2];

   // write to C# heap
   *vertices = sqrt(x);
   *(vertices + 1) = sqrt(y);
   *(vertices + 2) = sqrt(z);

   vertices += 3; // because it is a list of struct of 3 floats
}
```

Clean up the pinned handle from the C# side to resume the garbage collector.

```cs
gcVertices.Free();
```

As for strings, I believe the interop library has an implementation that handles pointer arithmetic and copying for you. You could probably just use a string type directly inside the exposed export function, as long as you specify how to marshal it with the `MarshalAs` attribute in C# and a library in C++ if you are not converting to the C type `char *`.